# Why does XML insertion on Oracle DB take a long time?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, ado.net, insert-update

I'm inserting many rows in a table having the following schema:

```
TABLE "SPACE"."WORKTABLE" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "AUTHOR" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "INSERTION_DATE" DATE, 
    "XML_DOCUMENT" "SYS"."XMLTYPE" 
   )
```

The insertion is being done using ADO.NET (`OracleXmlType`).
The first inserted row takes more than two minutes to finish; but after this insertion is done, all the following take much less time than the first one.

1. Why is this so?
2. Is this only related to the XML parsing being done when inserting the XML? Why (if yes) it happens only at the first insertion?
3. Can this time be reduced?

(please, if possible, document your answers)

UPDATE:
The code being executed is a simple insertion for at most 10 rows having an XML of 5500 character length. Also, I've already taken away the time taken to the connection to be opened as a cause of the lag.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO WORKTABLE VALUES ( " + rowID + ",'JBALVIN',1,'01-JAN-12',:xmldocument)";
using (OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand(sql, con))
{
    comm.Parameters.Add(":xmldocument", OracleDbType.XmlType);
    OracleXmlType xmlType = new OracleXmlType(con, entidadXML);
    comm.Parameters[0].Value = xmlType;
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

UPDATE:

We have noticed that the line causing the delay is `OracleXmlType xmlType = new OracleXmlType(con, entidadXML);`. Could it be fixed by stopping Oracle to check XML validity? If so... how can it be done? by a direct command using the connection?

Comment: What does "a long time" mean? What is an acceptable time limit? You haven't provided any code to indicate _why_ it might be taking a long time.

Comment: Yes, and can you show code? Perhaps there's a bug in your code instead of Oracle's?

Comment: @ben we are establishing data to set the scenario for many unit test. We expect this data to be inserted as if it were an insertion of a row having only numbers... or better: as fast as possible. Because insertion takes 30secs and we have more than 300 unit tests, to execute all unit tests could take an impractical amount of time. Also, the first insertion takes the most of the time, as I've stated on the question.

Comment: So what's the performance profile if you attempt to insert a record directly into the database using a SQL*Plus client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... after some guessing and googling, I found that if the URLs with the schema used on the XML are deleted (attributes `xmlns:xsi` and `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`), the insertion is done in the order of milliseconds. Sadly, this behavior is not documented at Oracle [OracleXmlType documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleXmlTypeClass.htm).